# Jquery 1.3 textarea selector starts with

Tags: html, jquery

I've some textareas starting with listing_ and some id. Both id and name has the same value.

I'd like to select them with jquery, but I can't find a solution for this version.

I tried something like this:

```js
$( "input[name^='listing']" )
```

but it does not work.

`$('#listing_2')` works for one.

Is my code wrong, or in version 1.3 was it a bit differently?

Comment: jQuery 1.3 is ancient and unsupported. I wouldn’t touch it with a barge pole.

Comment: Textarea elements are not input elements.

Comment: True, but I've to work with 1.3 unfortunately now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`textarea`s are not `input` tags.

Try:

```js
$( "textarea[name^='listing']" )
```